# How to call objects instance name with string? as3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
    private function DropFunc (e:MouseEvent):void

    {

        if(e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(Object (e.currentTarget + "Target")))
        {
            trace("good")
        }
        else{

        e.currentTarget.x = startPosX;
        e.currentTarget.y = startPosY;
        e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
        }

    }
```

I need to call object named currentTarget+Target in hittest object, what should i do ?

I am  newbie... 
sorry for silly question :X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question/code sample correctly, you're trying to dynamically access an instance by name.

Instead of attempting to cast it as an `Object`, you need to access it as a property of  the parent:

```
private function DropFunc (e:MouseEvent):void
{

    if(e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(this[e.currentTarget.name + "Target"]))
    {
        trace("good")
    }
    else{

    e.currentTarget.x = startPosX;
    e.currentTarget.y = startPosY;
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    }

}
```

The above example assumes that `this` is the parent of an object with the instance name of `e.currentTarget.name + "Target"`.

Comment: I tried what you said, but here is the error : Property [object MovieClip]Target not found on Stage_30 and there is no default value. at Stage_30/DropFunc(),

maybe it's because that that there is nothing on the stage , i am calling it from class. (They are only in library)

Comment: I apologize for my oversight. You would want to reference the `currentTarget`'s name. I've made an update to the code above.

Comment: Thanks, i suppose that works but another problem still exist,  ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property park_mc.NoFishing_mcTarget not found on Stage_30 and there is no default value.
 at Stage_30/DropFunc() <<< it can't find this movieclip on the stage, I am sure that  NoFishing_mcTarget does exist in park_mc (notice that park_mc is not on the stage... how can i let him see it ?)... what should i do now ?

Comment: Without a complete understanding of your project, there's no real way for me to help you debug your issue. I would have to know how you're adding objects to the display list, and how/where `DropFunc` is being added as an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the property of an object with string in the following way.

`objectInstance["property"]`.